# h2o scala code compile error not found object ai

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

I am trying to comile and run simple h2o scala code. But when I do sbt package I get errors.
Am I missing something in the sbt file

This is my h2o scala code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._

import ai.h2o.automl.AutoML
import ai.h2o.automl.AutoMLBuildSpec

import org.apache.spark.h2o._

object H2oScalaEg1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val sparkConf1 = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("H2oScalaEg1App")

  val sparkSession1 = SparkSession.builder.config(conf = sparkConf1).getOrCreate()

  val h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(sparkSession1.sparkContext)

  import h2oContext._

  import java.io.File

  import h2oContext.implicits._

  import water.Key

  }

}
```

And this is my sbt file.

```
name := "H2oScalaEg1Name"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / ""

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-core" % "3.22.1.3" % "runtime" pomOnly()
```

When I do sbt package I get these errors

```
[error] /home/myuser1/h2oScalaEg1/H2oScalaEg1.scala:7:8: not found: object ai

[error] import ai.h2o.automl.AutoML

[error]        ^

[error] /home/myuser1/h2oScalaEg1/H2oScalaEg1.scala:8:8: not found: object ai

[error] import ai.h2o.automl.AutoMLBuildSpec

[error]        ^
[error] /home/myuser1/h2oScalaEg1/H2oScalaEg1.scala:10:25: object h2o is not a member of package org.apache.spark

[error] import org.apache.spark.h2o._
[error]                         ^

[error] /home/myuser1/h2oScalaEg1/H2oScalaEg1.scala:20:20: not found: value H2OContext
[error]   val h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(sparkSession1.sparkContext)
[error]                    ^


[error] /home/myuser1/h2oScalaEg1/H2oScalaEg1.scala:28:10: not found: value water
[error]   import water.Key
[error]          ^
[error] 5 errors found
```

How can I fix this problem.

My spark version in spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7

Thanks,

marrel

Comment: Have you tried `sbt reload`?

Comment: Also looking at maven central, you could try `libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-core" % "3.22.1.5"` without the `pomOnly()`

Answer (score 1):

`pomOnly()` in `build.sbt` indicates to the dependency management handlers that jar libs/artifacts for this dependency should not be loaded and to only look for the metadata.

Try to use `libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-core" % "3.22.1.3"` instead.

**Edit 1:** Additionally I think you are missing (at least) one library dependency:
`libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-automl" % "3.22.1.3"`

see: https://search.maven.org/artifact/ai.h2o/h2o-automl/3.22.1.5/pom

**Edit 2:**
The last dependency you are missing is sparkling-water-core: 
`libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "sparkling-water-core_2.11" % "2.4.6"` should do the trick.

Here is the github of [sparkling-water/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/h2o](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/h2o)
.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: As suggested by you 
I did sbt reload
Then I tried with this in build.sbt. libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-core" % "3.22.1.3"
This 1 error was gone 
not found: value water . The remaining 4 errors remained the same.

Comment: Then I tried with this in build.sbt
libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-core" % "3.22.1.5"
I got the same errors.

Thanks for suggestions though.

Comment: Maybe you are missing more of those `ai.h2o` dependencies? So far you only have `h2o-core`. See: https://search.maven.org/search?q=ai.h2o

Comment: Yes, I was trying now with libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" %% "sparkling-water-core" % "0.2.0"
and this is when i saw your post. I will add libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-automl" % "3.22.1.3"
also and see if it compiles. Thanks.

Comment: libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-automl" % "3.22.1.3"
solved the 2 errors
[error] import ai.h2o.automl.AutoML
[error] import ai.h2o.automl.AutoMLBuildSpec

Thanks. 

I will try to figure out how to fix this 2 errors
[error] import org.apache.spark.h2o._
[error] /home/myuser1/h2oScalaEg1/H2oScalaEg1.scala:20:20: not found: value H2OContext

Comment: I updated my answer again, try this version of sparkling-water-core. I hope that's everything now.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestions today.

Comment: after adding
libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "h2o-automl" % "3.22.1.3"
libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" % "sparkling-water-core_2.11" % "2.4.6"
it gave me errors like this
unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit
so I deleted my ~/.ivy2 directory and then the build was success! Thank you very much for your suggestions !

Comment: I tried to mark 'this answer is useful' 
But I got message - 
Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, 
but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
So I will come back and mark 'this answer is useful'  after I get 15 reputations.

Comment: Glad it finally worked for you. The sparkling-water-core is only available for Scala 2.11 it seems. You can accept the answer as correct if it solved your issue by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: I tried to mark 'this answer is useful' But I got message - Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. So I will come back and mark 'this answer is useful' after I get 15 reputations. Thanks.